# XSLT parse escaped HTML stored in an attribute and convert that attribute's content into element's content

Tags: html, parsing, xslt

I'm stuck on what I think should be simple thing to do. I've been looking around, but didn't find the solution. Hope you will help me.

What I have is an XML element with an attribute that contains escaped HTML elements:

```
<Booking>    
  <BookingComments Type="RAM" comment="RAM name fred&lt;br/&gt;Tel 09876554&lt;br/&gt;Email fred@bla.com" />
</Booking>
```

What I need to get is parsed HTML elements and content from the @comment attribute to be a content of

element as follows:

```
<p>
  RAM name fred<br/>Tel 09876554<br/>Email fred@bla.com
<p>
```

Here is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn" version="1.0">


<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

 <xsl:template name="some-template">
   <p>Some text</p>
   <p>
      <xsl:copy-of
        select="/Booking/BookingComments[lower-case(@Type)='ram'][1]/@comment"/>
   </p>     
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've read that copy-of is a good way to restore escaped HTML elements back to proper elements. In this specific case, because it's initially an attribute the copy-of translates it into attribute as well. So I get:

```
<p comment="RAM name fred<br/&gt;Tel 09876554<br/&gt;Email fred@bla.com"></p>
```

Which isn't what I want.

If I use apply-templates instead of copy-of, as in:

```
<p>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/Booking/BookingComments[lower-case(@Type)='ram'[1]/@comment"/>
</p>
```

I get p's content simply as text, not restored HTML elements.

```
<p>RAM name fred&lt;br/&gt;Tel 09876554&lt;br/&gt;Email fred@bla.com</p>
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvous. I would really appreciate any help and tips!

Comment: "I've read that copy-of is a good way to restore escaped HTML elements back to proper elements." : where did you read that? I didn't think it was possible to automagically un-escape html, but I'd be most happy to learn this trick.

Comment: @Roland Bouman. I think I frased myself not very well. I was relying on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105176/xslt-parsing-html-embedded-in-xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using a dedicated template:

```
<!-- check if lower-casing @Type is really necessary -->
<xsl:template name="BookingComments[lower-case(@Type)='ram']/@comment">
  <p>
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
  </p>     
</xsl:template>
```

This way you could simply apply templates to the attribute. Note that disabling output escaping has the potential to generate ill-formed output.

Answer (score 1):

You could bind an extension function parse() which parses a string into a nodeset. The exact mechanism will depend on your XSLT engine.

In Xalan, we can take the following static method:

```
public class MyExtension
{
    public static NodeIterator Parse( string xml );
}
```

and use it like so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java"
    exclude-result-prefixes="java"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="BookingComments">
        <xsl:copy-of select="java:package.name.MyExtension.Parse(string(@comment))" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```