# Target and format HTML which is contained inside a XML's attribute using XSL transformation

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am using the XSL-FO transformation to transform an XML to PDF. In this XML I have various fields which are just copied to the PDF without formatting.

Some fields have the value as HTML stored in an attribute and those I need to format. I am having troubles targeting and formatting this HTML using XSL templates.

I tried with various selectors and templates to make XSL a formatted output of the mentioned html.

This is an example of the XML, where you can see the valueString field with the HTML inside the 'value' attribute.

```xml
<item>
     <linkId value="linkId1"/>
     <text value="This is some title text"/>
     <answer>
         <valueString
             value="&lt;p>&lt;strong>This is the html value&lt;/strong>&lt;/p>&#xa;&lt;p>which I am not able to format&lt;/p>"/>
     </answer>
 </item>
```

I tried to target and format this html using this template (e.g. for the strong html element):

```xml
    <xsl:template match="valueString[@value='strong']">
        <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:inline>
    </xsl:template>
```

And I invoked the template using:

```xml
<xsl:apply-templates select="n1:answer/n1:valueString"></xsl:apply-templates>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You would need to have support for an additional "parse" step e.g. in XSLT 3 `<xsl:temlate match="valueString"><xsl:apply-templates select="parse-xml-fragment(@value)"/></xsl:template>` and then `<xsl:template match="strong"><fo:inline font-weight="bold">...</xsl:template>`. Do you use XSLT on the Java or .NET platform where you could plug in Saxon 9.8 or 9.9 HE as the XSLT processor to have support for `parse-xml-fragment`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSLT parse escaped HTML stored in an attribute and convert that attribute's content into element's content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310618/xslt-parse-escaped-html-stored-in-an-attribute-and-convert-that-attributes-cont)

Comment: I flagged this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310618/xslt-parse-escaped-html-stored-in-an-attribute-and-convert-that-attributes-cont although I can also say that maybe the other question does not answer it very well or comprehensively either

Comment: Well, I don't really have a problem with unescaping the HTML from the XML attribute. The problem I am having is passing that unescaped HTML through the templates where each of the HTML elements gets styled for the XSL-FO output/

Comment: Which XSLT (not XSL-FO) version are you using?  An solution using XSLT 2.0 or XSLT 3.0 would simpler and more concise than one using XSLT 1.0.

Comment: sadly XSLT 1.0 is used